# Consider $(f\Box g) (z)=\inf_{x+y=z}(f(x)+f(y))$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider $$(f\Box g) (z)=\inf_{x+y=z}(f(x)+g(y))$$

Find two convex functions $f$ and $g$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that the infimum given above is never a minimum.

Can anyone help with finding such functions?

Comment: The rhs does not depend on $g$, did you mean $f(x) + g(y)$ ?

Comment: yes I did. Thanks

Comment: Why did you use $\Box$ here and $\oplus$ [elsewhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507013/determine-the-domain-of-f-oplus-g-in-terms-of-the-domains-of-f-and-g) for the same operation?

Comment: I am working out of two books, which use the different notation. It just depends on which book I have in my hand at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example would be $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = -x$:
$$
(f\Box g) (z) = \inf_{x \in \mathbb R} (f(x) + g(z-x)) = 
\inf_{x \in \mathbb R} (2x - z) = - \infty \, .
$$

$f(x) = e^x$, $g(x) = e^{-x}$ is an example where the infimum
is finite:
$$
(f\Box g) (z) = \inf_{x \in \mathbb R} (f(x) + g(z-x)) = 
\inf_{x \in \mathbb R} e^x (1 + e^{-z}) = 0
$$
and the infimum is not a minimum because $e^x (1 + e^{-z}) > 0$
for all $x$ and $z$.

Slightly more general, you can take any  convex
function $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which does not have a minimum,
and define $g$ by $g(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: So, if I wanted to find two convex functions $f$ and $g$ such that the infimum is always a minimum would $f(x)=g(x)=x$ work for me, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes, that would be an example (and $(f\Box g)(z) = z$).

Comment: @MartinR In your simple example $g$ is not convex. Your second example works only because the conjugate of $f$ and $g$ are not continuous. But if those conjugates have a common continuity point the convolution is attained.

Comment: @NeutralElement: $g(x) = -x$ is *linear* and thus convex ($g''(x) \equiv 0$). – Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I missread it.